# How to decode HTML quote entities in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string `&#39;71` which, when decode, should contain '71.

I have used `html_entity_decode`, `addslashes` and `htmlspecialchars_decode` and none of these will turn this back into '71.

The following code is an example of what I've tried...

```
$name = html_entity_decode($string);
```

Any ideas? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) takes a second parameter that you need to make use of:

```
$string = '&#39;71';
$name = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES);
echo $name;
```

See the [**Parameters: flags**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php#refsect1-function.html-entity-decode-parameters) section in the documentation.

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/206144)

I find that I need `html_entity_decode()` to decode quotes more often than not. If the same goes for you, write your own function:

```
html_entity_decode_wq($s){
    return html_entity_decode($s, ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

Comment: so the 'aposthrophe is a *quote*

Comment: Perfect, simple, yet so effective! Thanks George.

Comment: @DOCASAREL A single quote, yes.

Comment: did you know that or did you try? i was just about to start with the flags %)P

Comment: @DOCASAREL I've read before. They have different uses of course, and in the English language, they are different characters. Most computer languages however, use the same character. Here's a read: http://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-list/2008-June/msg00361.html

Comment: @sark9012 Glad to have helped.

Comment: This is my article about these functions, visit this [URL](http://qiita.com/mpyw/items/939c526dd5de6619b565) just for reference. It's written in Japanese. So you should use an online translator.